# Firebase login works sometimes while it doesnt other times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                         GoogleSignInResult result = 
                         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(GoogleLoginActivity.this,"Something went wrong 
                 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code usually works when I connect my device via USB and run it or when I use the emulator but when I try to do the same after generating a signed APK I get the something went wrong error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show __exactly__ the error you're getting.

Comment: Can't really show whats wrong as I am facing the problem only when I run the app through Signed APK the app works just fine when I run it via USB cable

Comment: You can certainly run your release signed app on your phone and capture logs from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add all the possible SHA-1 hashes for your app into the Firebase console.  It sounds like you added the hash for you debug signing key, but not the release key.  Repeat what you did for your debug key, except this time for your release key.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: I did the same for the release key but yet after repeated attempts the situation is still the same.

Comment: Updating my SHA-1 hashes worked this time. Thank you so much